# abc.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, github

I sync from git hub desktop Master branch then I open abc.xcodeprof file I can not open error message

[abc.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed.]

[image]

i am remove those <<<<<<< HEAD, ======= and >>>>>>> origin/master lines so it would look like this

```
9ADAAC6A15DCEF6A0019ACA8 /* BuyPriceBtn.png in Resources */,

52FD7F3D15DCEAEF009E9322 /* discussionForm.zip in Resources */,
```

then save file and again same error **abc.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed.**

Comment: revert latest changes on project file

Answer (score 3):

This often happens when you have some conflicts inside your .xcodeproj and you missed something.

You have two possible solutions -

1. Revert changes (for example, git checkout 'file name') and add changes manually
2. Use merge tool in order to find the problem [tutorial for merge tool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps

1. Go to your.xcodeproj
2. Right click on it and click show in pakage content.
3. open to .pbxproj  and search one by one with
   a. .mine
   b. ====
   c. >>>>
   d. <<<<
4. Remove the line
5. Save it and you are ready to go

Answer (score 3):

I followed the above steps and I was still unable to open the `.xcworkspace` project, I stumbled across [`kin`](https://github.com/Karumi/Kin) which validates your `.pbxproj` file.

`kin` found some syntax errors, after fixing those (and resolving conflicts), I was able to open my project.

Comment: Really helpful!

Comment: FYI, to install 'kin' on a new Mac, you probably want to run "pip3 install kin"